# Pattern Recognition and Algorithms vs. Neural Networks

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I was reading a book about how the brain uses hierarchies of patterns to recognize and model concepts and sensory information, like letters and words written in a book, or physical objects, or other things of that nature. But I am a little confused about how one would proceed in implementing a simple version of such a system. I have a few questions about this.

- First, what exactly are all the characteristics of a pattern in this context?
- And what is the most fundamental element in such a hierarchy of patterns?
- Is there a way to recognize them by means of an algorithm as opposed to a neural network?
- If I write a program to formulate patterns from a line of pixels, that may be somewhat easy, but how would I do it with a two-dimensional array of pixels?
- Is there a difference between visual patterns, and mathematical patterns?
- Is there a difference in the way that one would recognize the patterns in a number sequence as opposed to a sequence of features in an image?

I would really like some help understanding this since most of the information I find requires a great mathematical background which I have so far not obtained.

Comment: Don't be afraid of a new-line here and there and some formatting. Also, that may be too many questions.

Answer (score 1):

Both recognition of mathematical patterns and image features use the same type of "cognition" but you have various different implementations that specialize for each. In images, you are dealing with a pixel color (for ex: 255,255,255) and its relation to pixels surrounding it (two-dimensional array).

For ease of computation, most algos go through the following:

- Go through each of the horizontal line then through each vertical line and create an array of pixel differences (preferably in L*a*b colorspace).
- Then by tweaking some parameters, you can isolate unique "objects" that are continuous in both x and y directions
- Create a logical tree of objects and their positions on the image

If you want to do things a bit differently, then you would use a Fast Fourier Transform and follow the patterns there. If you are working with regular number patterns, the principles are the same.